# java applet doesn't run when deployed, but works when run in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

Below is my very rough applet code. At the very bottom, I execute client.clientProcess();

```
import javax.swing.*;

import com.pega.Messaging.Client;
import com.pega.Messaging.MessagingHelper;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PRPCPassCrackApplet extends JApplet{


    JLabel message;

    JLabel lpmsg;
    JTextField localPort;    

    JLabel snmsg;
    JTextField serverName;

    JLabel spmsg;
    JTextField serverPort;

    JButton button; 
    JLabel error;

    public void init(){

        setSize(600,150);  
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        message = new JLabel("Client Parameters\n");
        lpmsg = new JLabel("Local Port:  ");
        snmsg = new JLabel("Server Name: ");
        spmsg = new JLabel("Server Port: ");
        localPort = new JTextField();
        serverName = new JTextField();
        serverPort = new JTextField();
        localPort.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 10));
        serverName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 10));
        serverPort.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 10));

        button = new JButton("Send To Server");  
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,10));

        error = new JLabel("");
        error.setForeground(Color.red);

        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2)); 
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        window.add(message);
        window.add(new JLabel(""));
        window.add(lpmsg);
        window.add(localPort);
        window.add(snmsg);
        window.add(serverName);
        window.add(spmsg);
        window.add(serverPort);
        window.add(button);
        window.add(error);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent push){
            String lp = localPort.getText();
            String sn = serverName.getText();
            String sp = serverPort.getText();
            int lpint = -1;
            int spint = -1;
            ServerSocket listenSocket = null;
            Socket socketToServer = null;

            try{
                lpint = Integer.parseInt(lp);
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                error.setText("Local Port is not a number");
                return;
            }

            try{
                spint = Integer.parseInt(sp);
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                error.setText("Server Port is not a number");
                return;
            }

            try{
                listenSocket = new ServerSocket(lpint);
            }catch(Exception e){
                error.setText("Could not open local port: " + lp +". Choose another.");
                return;
            } finally{
                try {
                    listenSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }

            try{
                //open connection to server
                InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(sn);
                socketToServer = new Socket(serverAddress, spint);
                //create initial connection 
                OutputStream os = socketToServer.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                //report in
                String status = "ping";
                bw.write(MessagingHelper.createPacket(status, sn, lp, ""));
                bw.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                error.setText("Can't connect to Server: " + sn + " on port: " + sp);
                return;
            }finally{
                try {
                    socketToServer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
            error.setText("Beginning Execution");
            error.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            button.setVisible(false);
            Client client = new Client(spint, sn, lpint, true);
            client.clientProcess();     

        }
    }
}
```

When I run this in eclipse, my program runs happily and finishes correctly, however I'm exporting the jar via right click > Export > JAR file I cannot run my applet with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Client Testing</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1 id="header1"> Distributed Brute Force Attacks </h1>


<applet
class="blah.blah.blah.blah.Applet" <!--not actually blah.blah I had to obfuscate-->
archive="client.jar"
code="blah.blah.blah.blah.Applet.class"
width="1000"
height="250"
vspace="10"
hspace="10"
align="center"
alt="You need Java to run this Applet"
name="clientApplet"
mayscript >
</applet>


</body>

</html>
```

If it helps in eclipse I have "Export generated class files and resources" and "Export Java source files and resources" checked, and no Main class defined.

The applet shows up properly and does the error checking properly, but it never seems to run that clientProcess. What can I do to allow a user to run my code through the applet?

Comment: I'd probably try to help, but you are opening a server socket in an applet called 'Distributed Brute Force Attacks'. Yea, no.

Comment: @Perception What is Distibuted Brute Force Attacks?

Comment: right so the program is to use multiple machines to attack a webserver for work. which is the reason I can't show the applet's name, since it has my work's name. the webserver is part of work and this is allowed as I am on our security team. I understand your balking at the question, and feel free to remain balked, but it is not illegal to brute force one's own machine.

Comment: @home clientProcess will receive messages from the server and execute the brute force, then report whether it was successful, then waits to see if the server asks it to do something else

Comment: I suspect that the cause is usual - missing packages.

Comment: @tophersmith116 - you must understand my skepticism. Especially considering you are on your companies security team. But, I will give you the benefit of a doubt ... print out your stacktraces, I am sure you discover very quickly that there are some security exceptions being thrown by your Applet.

Comment: @Perception yes of course. I'm getting quite used to skepticism as part of this job. I think I might spit everything out to file, as my tomcat isn't picking up my stacktraces (they're already in place but not appearing anywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that class path is set.When you are running this applet in eclipse all class files are present in class path including jars.

Comment: Yes I had done this. I don't know what's going on, but I think it has to do with my threads dying suddenly...